# Splash stops with error "unregister_netdevice: waiting for lo to become free"

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, kernel, splash-js-render

```
kernel:[1476369.644116] unregister_netdevice: waiting for lo to become free. Usage count = 1
```

I got that error then Splash will stop working and I have to run the docker from the beginning again. I heard it's related with docker. How to stop getting this issue?

Is it related to low RAM? My linux server's spec is 512MB RAM and 1vCPU.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're operating system is not using the latest kernel and is on a 3.10.x kernel, the error you've encountered is due to an issue in the kernel.
The upstream kernel based on 4.4.22 has this issue fixed but it's awaiting a backport to the current kernel 3.10.x

Link: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1379767

Depending on your operating system, there are a few workaround but if you do further research, you'll see this error still occurs on the following systems and kernels:

- Ubuntu 16.04: 4.4.0-64
- CentOS 7: 3.10.0-514
- Amazon Linux: 4.4.39

** based on the time of writing

Comment: Couldn't post the additional links:
References to some links: 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5618
https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/254